# how to stop jmeter from writing anything in the .csv results file

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Straight and short, i want jmeter to stop writing any output in the .csv results file.

I've heard that preventing the creation of the file is not possible however we can set the results file configuration properties to decide what values to output so basically i went over all those properties, i did read them all and i set the ones that i could set to false to false, the ones that i could set to none to none and the ones that i could set to their default values to their default values, in theory the file shouldn't print anything and remain at 0kbs, however this is not the case the file still grows in size and it is printing a zero every line like these:

```
0
0
0
0
```

and this is how i have my properties in the user.properties file

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=none
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=
jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

Where is that 0 coming from? is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the results file just don't provide its location, i.e. omit this [`-l` bit](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) when you [launch JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/):

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx
```

The above command will trigger the test execution but **no .jtl results file will be created.**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to create a .csv file when your not storing anything into it.
Maybe just don't give any file name here

[image]